# PDF/A validation

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdfa, acrofields

I am trying to validate a self created PDF file against the PDF/A-1b specification but I am getting below errors (For the validation I used the Apache PDFBox Preflight library. The version for Apache PDFBox and Preflight is 2.0.15)

3.1.1 : Invalid Font definition, Helvetica: some required fields are missing from the Font dictionary: firstChar, lastChar, widths.

3.1.3 : Invalid Font definition, Helvetica: FontFile entry is missing from FontDescriptor

3.1.1 : Invalid Font definition, ZapfDingbats: some required fields are missing from the Font dictionary: firstChar, lastChar, widths.

3.1.3 : Invalid Font definition, ZapfDingbats: FontFile entry is missing from FontDescriptor

7.11.1 : Error on MetaData

How can I overcome above problems.
Thank you in advance

```
PDResources resources = new PDResources();
resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), 
pdfPage.getText1Font());
String deafultAppearance = "/Helv 12 Tf 0 g";

form.setDefaultResources(resources);
form.setDefaultAppearance(deafultAppearance);
pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(form);


   metadata.createAndAddPDFAExtensionSchemaWithDefaultNS(); 
 metadata.getPDFExtensionSchema().addNamespace("http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/schema#", "pdfaSchema");
                 metadata.getPDFExtensionSchema().addNamespace("http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/property#", "pdfaProperty");
                metadata.getPDFExtensionSchema().addNamespace("http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id/", "pdfaid");
    XMPSchema uaSchema = new XMPSchema(XMPMetadata.createXMPMetadata(),
                        "pdfaSchema", "pdfaSchema", "pdfaSchema");
    uaSchema.setTextPropertyValue("schema", "PDF/A Accessibility Schema");
    uaSchema.setTextPropertyValue("namespaceURI", "http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id/");
                uaSchema.setTextPropertyValue("prefix", "pdfaid");
    XMPSchema uaProp = new XMPSchema(XMPMetadata.createXMPMetadata(),
                        "pdfaProperty", "pdfaProperty", "pdfaProperty");
    uaProp.setTextPropertyValue("name", "part");
    uaProp.setTextPropertyValue("valueType", "Integer");
    uaProp.setTextPropertyValue("category", "internal");
    uaProp.setTextPropertyValue("description", "Indicates, which part of ISO 14289 standard is followed");
    uaSchema.addUnqualifiedSequenceValue("property", uaProp);
    metadata.getPDFExtensionSchema().addBagValue("schemas", uaSchema);
    metadata.getPDFExtensionSchema().setPrefix("pdfaid");
    metadata.getPDFExtensionSchema().setTextPropertyValue("part", "1");
```

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Did you create the file yourself completely? See also the `CreatePDFA.java` example in the source code download.

Comment: Yes, I have created the file myself completely. I have already seen CreatePDFA.java.

Comment: The initial error messages suggest that you didn't embed your fonts. And in the XMP code I miss the conformance ("B").

Comment: How I embed the correctly?

Comment: Use `PDType0Font.load()` instead of the standard 14 fonts. Additionally, for acroform fields, the third parameter should be `false` (don't subset).

Comment: If I use PDType0Font.load() then I get below error: Glyph error, The character code 74 in the font program "AAAVVE+Helvetica" is missing from the Character Encoding. You were right about conformance ("B"). Now I do not have the error for metadata anymore

Comment: "AAAVVE+Helvetica" means it is subset. Were you loading a subset from an existing PDF ?! Don't do that.

Comment: You are right. If I use PDType0Font.load() with the third argument to be false then I do not get any validation error. Now pdf has been validated correcty but I have 2 new issues.1) I get too many info of the same message (OpenType Layout tables used in font Helvetica are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored) and 2 if I open the file with XODO then I do not see the strings correctly in textfields and comboboxes. Since you resolve my initial post I would like you to write the answer in order for me to accept it as a correct answer. Should I post a new question about my 2 new problems?

Comment: Will do. The "OpenType Layout tables used in font Helvetica are not implemented" is harmless. Just ignore it, This has been a PITA for a long time, I must remember to remove it. Re the other problem, create a new question and share the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font related messages are because you used the standard 14 type 1 font objects, e.g. `PDType1Font.HELVETICA`. PDF/A-1b requires all fonts to be embedded. Thus use `PDType0Font.load()` to load your fonts. For acroform fields, make sure to use a method that has the third parameter `false` to prevent subsetting.

The XMP related messages are because you forgot to set the conformance to "B". See also `CreatePDFA.java` in the examples subproject of the source code download.